# JQuery and JSON.stringify misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, stringify

In studying Javascript and JQuery and I felt in a black hole for a very basic code. I need to convert a JS object to string usign JSON.stringify.
The object is built by assembling pieces of data from different sources.
To simplify the matter, this is a bare example with an Input field to enter the object's data:

```
<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8" /></head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt" value="{Name: 'John Smith'  ,  Value: 99}">`
<button id="test" type="text" value="3">TEST</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{   
$("#test").on('click',test);
}); 

function test() {
    query = $("#txt").val();
    json = JSON.stringify(query);
    console.log("query="+json); //"{Name: 'John Smith'  ,  Value: 99}"

    query={ Name: 'John Smith', Value: 99 };
    json = JSON.stringify(query);
    console.log("query="+json); //{"Name":"John Smith","Value":99}

    return false;
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you see, the input text is not 'stringified' while the inline code is.
Where is the error?
Thanks

Comment: can you add a fiddle ?

Comment: If you try to `stringify` a string, it will just put it as it is. `$('#txt').val()` is already a string.

Answer (score 2):

> As you see, the input text is not 'stringified' while the inline code is. Where is the error?

The value you read from the input is *already a string*, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Value fetched from an input field is already of type `string`; and
2. JSON doesn't really like single quotes to tell you the truth. So, the value you've set (`value="{Name: 'John Smith'  ,  Value: 99}`) isn't a valid JSON format as per [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

**Solution**

You can try removing the first `JSON.stringify` usage line from your code. And, switch the quotes in the input field value as: `value='{"Name": "John Smith", "Value": 99}'`. This should do the trick for you.

Comment: So  I do not understand what 'stringify' is supposed to do. I red that it should add the missing quotes and convert the single quotes to double quotes, beside of removing extra spaces. I have several inputs and I wish that stringify takes care of formatting them all at once when simply concatenated (i.e, height=40 +','+ width=20... with '=' replaced by colon. Actually, when I try to Post with Ajax a data={"Name":"John Smith","Value":99}, with datatype=JSON, I get 'Invalid character in position 1' or something similar. That's why I'm trying JSON.stringify.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` just converts the JSON object you pass to it into a valid `JSONString`. If you wish to get a pretty, well-formatted JSON then try this: `json = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse($("#txt").val()));`. Ensure that you've flipped the quotes like i said before you try this.